# Display Nested JSON Data Object in HTML Table

Tags: javascript, json, html, knockout.js

I have a JSON object that also includes a nested items - TagList and TaskRecordList.

I want to display EntityCode and EntityName as a 'parent' row and then display the TagList and then the last nested layer - TaskRecordList data below this.

How do I do this using Knockout?

```js
var viewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
   
    // variables   
    self.taskRecords = ko.observableArray([
         {
        "EntityCode": "SP00",
        "EntityName": "Sample",
        "TagList": [
            {
                "TagID": 3,
                "TagName": "Level 3",
                "TaskRecordList": [
                    {
                        "TaskRecordID": 33,
                        "TaskName": "Cash",
                        "Period": "2017-05-16T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "TaskRecordID": 34,
                        "TaskName": "CashTest",
                        "Period": "2017-05-16T00:00:00"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "TagID": 2,
                "TagName": "Level 5",
                "TaskRecordList": [
                    {
                        "TaskRecordID": 27,
                        "TaskName": "FileIN",
                        "Period": "2017-05-16T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "TaskRecordID": 21,
                        "TaskName": "FileTest",
                        "Period": "2017-05-16T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "TaskRecordID": 35,
                        "TaskName": "OTE Rec",
                        "Period": "2017-05-16T00:00:00"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "EntityCode": "DEMO",
        "EntityName": "Demo Fund",
        "TagList": []
    }
    ]); 
   
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Entity Code</th>
                <th>Entity Name</th>
                <th>TagID</th>
                <th>TagName</th>
                <th>TaskRecordID</th>
                <th>TaskName</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="sortable" data-bind="foreach: taskRecords">
            <tr class="ui-state-default ui-state-disabled" >
                <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: EntityCode"></td>
                <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: EntityName"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-bind="foreach: TagList">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: TagID"></td>
                <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: TagName"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-bind="foreach: TaskRecordList">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: TaskRecordID"></td>
                <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: TaskName"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2L1ny8r/6/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're almost there. Your data structure is inconsistent currently so I'm guessing you want your objects to be `{"TagID":3, "TagName": "L3"}` instead of `{"TagID":5}, {"TagName": "L5"}` otherwise you have two different object formats and the binding will fail when it tries to find "TagName" in the first object, and also when it tries to find "TagID" in the second object.

Then your bindings need to be adjusted so that there is a foreach within the parent foreach. You can move the first one up to the tbody so that the second foreach becomes nested within it.

```js
var viewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
   
    // variables   
    self.taskRecords = ko.observableArray([
     {
       EntityCode: 1, 
        EntityName: "ManualItems", 
        TaskRecordList: [
         {"TagID":3, "TagName": "L3"}
         ]},
     {
       EntityCode: 2, 
        EntityName: "Trades", 
        TaskRecordList: [
         {"TagID":5, "TagName": "L5"}
         ]}
    ]); 
   
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Entity Code</th>
                <th>Entity Name</th>
                <th>TagID</th>
                <th>TagName</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="sortable" data-bind="foreach: taskRecords">
            <tr class="ui-state-default ui-state-disabled" >
                <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: EntityCode"></td>
                <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: EntityName"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-bind="foreach: TaskRecordList">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: TagID"></td>
                <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: TagName"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Hi, I now have a 3rd layer to the object. How do I bind this? http://jsfiddle.net/v2L1ny8r/6/

Comment: @Kevin Do you want the third layer on the same row or a new row below the second layer?

Comment: Jason, as a new row below the 2nd layer

Comment: @Kevin then you'll need to use the containerless syntax to extend the parent foreach around both `<tr>` elements. http://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/v2L1ny8r/7/

Answer (score 0):

@jasonspake thank you. That works now - http://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/v2L1ny8r/7/

```js
var viewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
   
    // variables   
    self.taskRecords = ko.observableArray([
         {
        "EntityCode": "SP00",
        "EntityName": "Sample",
        "TagList": [
            {
                "TagID": 3,
                "TagName": "Level 3",
                "TaskRecordList": [
                    {
                        "TaskRecordID": 33,
                        "TaskName": "Cash",
                        "Period": "2017-05-16T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "TaskRecordID": 34,
                        "TaskName": "CashTest",
                        "Period": "2017-05-16T00:00:00"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "TagID": 2,
                "TagName": "Level 5",
                "TaskRecordList": [
                    {
                        "TaskRecordID": 27,
                        "TaskName": "FileIN",
                        "Period": "2017-05-16T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "TaskRecordID": 21,
                        "TaskName": "FileTest",
                        "Period": "2017-05-16T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "TaskRecordID": 35,
                        "TaskName": "OTE Rec",
                        "Period": "2017-05-16T00:00:00"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "EntityCode": "DEMO",
        "EntityName": "Demo Fund",
        "TagList": []
    }
    ]); 
   
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Entity Code</th>
                <th>Entity Name</th>
                <th>TagID</th>
                <th>TagName</th>
                <th>TaskRecordID</th>
                <th>TaskName</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="sortable" data-bind="foreach: taskRecords">
            <tr class="ui-state-default ui-state-disabled" >
                <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: EntityCode"></td>
                <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: EntityName"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <!--ko foreach: TagList-->
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: TagID"></td>
                <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: TagName"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-bind="foreach: TaskRecordList">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: TaskRecordID"></td>
                <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: TaskName"></td>
            </tr>
            <!--/ko-->
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.